# Google Places AutoComplete SearchBar Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, uisearchbar, google-places

I have a problem with the bug about usage of Google API on the below picture. I don't know how it did happened. I implemented how google samples shows.

Language is Objective-C and GooglePlaces is installed by CocoaPods

[image: Search Icon and PlaceHolder are on top of each other]